# "In the comfort of" or "at the comfort of"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, at-in

Which sentence is correct?

> Buy tickets *in* the comfort of your home

or

> Buy tickets *at* the comfort of your home

I saw the first one written on a hoarding but I feel the second one is more acceptable. Please explain which one is correct and why.

Comment: I would actually recommend "*from* the comfort of your home" over either of the given choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preposition is applying to the *comfort*, not to the location.  So it would be:

> We ordered *in comfort*.  **(correct)**
>
> We ordered *at comfort*.

Another example:

> We sat in the light of the moon.

Here it is hopefully more clear that you're talking about sitting *in the light* rather than *in the moon*!

Answer (score 2):

The first is definitely correct.

Although you are AT your home, your are IN comfort.

Comment: I'd say "_in_ my home" too.

Comment: I might say 'in my home', as in inside the building. But you would also say 'at home' where referring to location: 'Where are you?'. 'At home.'

Answer (score 1):

I've never been invited to do anything at the comfort of my home and don't expect to be.

Comment: I'd would have said too that *in the comfort of my home* was the correct form. 
 But I googled *at the comfort of your home* and came upon an impressive number of hits. So it is being used (and not only on sites run by non native English speakers. The thing is when does usage become acceptable?

Comment: The thing is, what do you mean by acceptable? :)

Comment: Neither the Corpus of Contemporary American English, nor the British National Corpus returns any records for ‘at the comfort of your home’ or ‘at the comfort of your own home’ and nor does nGrams.